# How to specify linker option to not use a particular address space while generating the vmlinux kernel Image?

Tags: linux-kernel, linker, embedded-linux, yocto

I have an address space in RAM that is used for something else -
0x00100000 to - 4096 bytes.  I want to specify a linker option in Yocto , linux kernel to not use that address space starting from 0x00100000 to - 4096 bytes.
I am unsure about the syntax here like - 
ROM 0 (NOLOAD)

```
  SECTIONS
{
         ROM 0 (NOLOAD) : { 0x00100000 - 4096  }
    . = KERNELBASE;

    _text = .;
    _stext = .;

    /*
```

Comment: To modify any fetched files from recipe, you can use yocto patches. have look here -> https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-patching-code